# Change ImageView as per user input

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I'm using Numberpicker in which I'm taking input of String.

```
    public final String Branch[] = {"Branch","Comp", "Civil", "Mech", "Chem", "EnTC"};
```

I'm sending this data in Firebase. In other activity I'm taking data from firebase using getter. I want to change my ImageView as per user Input. If user choose **Comp** as input,then **tecomp** should be shown.Simpilarly for mech ,temch should shown. But in switch case my activity get force shut down. My code

```
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
            year =  userProfile.getYear();
            branch = userProfile.getBranch();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(TimetableActivity.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    switch (branch){
        case "Comp":
            timetable.setImageResource(R.drawable.ttcomp);
            break;
        case "Mech":
            timetable.setImageResource(R.drawable.ttmech);
            break;
        case "Civil":
            timetable.setImageResource(R.drawable.ttcivil);
            break;
        case "EnTC":
            timetable.setImageResource(R.drawable.ttentc);
            break;
    }
```

Xml file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Timetable" />
```

Comment: can you please post the complete activity code?

Comment: Questions. 
1. By force shut down do you mean crash? If it crashes can you look for the crashlog in the Debug console log? 
2. Where do you get the String "branch"? Did you put a breakpoint and make sure that you are getting the expected value for branch? 3. Did you check if timetable is not null?

Comment: Sir, other content is not related to this, String is in MainActivity.java and other code is in other activity TimetableActivity.java.

Comment: @GeorgeArokiam, yes my app crashes when I use this Switch case and timetable 
input is mandatory for user.

Comment: It would be difficult to guess what the problem is util you provide what error you got.

Comment: @UmerFarooq sir, error is added in quetion.

Comment: I still don't see the error.  Please post the logcat that is produced when your app crashes to see exactly what caused the crash.